# iPhone:Convert NSString 123-123-1234 into (123) 123-1234

Tags: iphone

I have string like 123-123-1234 so I want to convert string into this format 
(123) 123-1234 so any idea to develop this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think something like this:

```
NSString *list = @"123-123-1234";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-%@", [listItem objectAtIndex:0], [listItem objectAtIndex:1], [listItem objectAtIndex:2]];
```

Comment: U FORGOT TO - IN UR output FORMAT

Answer (score 1):

**TESTED CODE: 100% WORKS**

```
NSString *inputString=@"123-123-1234";


NSArray *TotalString=[inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];


NSString *outputString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-%@",[TotalString objectAtIndex:0],[TotalString objectAtIndex:1],[TotalString objectAtIndex:2]];

NSLog(@"outputString is : %@ \n\n",outputString);
```

**OUTPUT:**
    outputString is : (123) 123-1234

---

**For Dynamic Sollution:**

**NOTE:** if u have more dashes with ur string then it is really hard code everything with objectAtIndex with number 0,1,2,....

moreover it will crash if it has unexpected length

so here is the solution for this

```
NSString *inputString=@"123-123-1234";


NSArray *TotalString=[inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];


NSMutableString *outputString=[NSMutableString string]; 
for (NSMutableString *obj in TotalString) {


    if ([TotalString objectAtIndex:0] == obj && [outputString length]<=0) {

        outputString=[[outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@"(%@)",obj] mutableCopy];


    }
    else if ([TotalString objectAtIndex:1] == obj) {

        outputString=[[outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@",@" ",obj] mutableCopy];


    }
    else {
        outputString=[[outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@"-%@",obj] mutableCopy];

    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**
    outputString is : (123) 123-1234

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString * original = @"123-123-1234";
NSArray * components = [original componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
NSString * first = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)",[components objectAtIndex:0] ];
NSString * second = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",[components objectAtIndex:1],[components objectAtIndex:2]];
NSString * finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",first,second];
NSLog(@"Final Result = %@",finalString);
```

Answer (score 1):

NSString *str = @"123-123-1234";

NSArray *arrForDate = [str componentsSeparatedByString: @"-"];

NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-%@",[arrForDate objectAtIndex:0],[arrForDate 
objectAtIndex:1],[arrForDate objectAtIndex:2]];

NSLog(@"str1 %@",str1);

Answer (score 0):

NSString *list = @"123-123-1234";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-%@", [listItem objectAtIndex:0], [listItem objectAtIndex:1], [listItem objectAtIndex:2]];

Comment: iPhone:Convert NSString 123-123-1234 into (123) 123-1234

Comment: iPhone:Convert NSString 123-123-1234 into (123) 123-1234